# JSON data type with inline datepicker (calendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm developing web application while/for learning web development that has a calendar widget/portlet/sidebar thingy. I used in-lined bootstraps datepicker.You can click on any date and get all the posts where "date_event" == "date_clicked" (I'm using PHP MVC structure and MySQL). All is well on this front.

I got stuck trying to get all the dates on the calendar to get highlighted if post exists for that day of month. I used AJAX and JSON to get all post dates corresponding to currently selected month, this is triggered by datepicker.changeMonth. I get a nice JSON object (or is it?) from my php function sent to browser:

calendar.php (controller)

```
function events_per_month($time) {

    $date = explode("-", $time);
    $month = $date[0];
    $year = $date[1];

    $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    $end = mktime(23, 59, 0, $month, date('t', $start), $year);

    $start1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
    $end1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);

    echo json_encode($this->post_m->get_calendar($start1, $end1));
}
```

post_m.php (model)

```
function get_calendar($start, $end) {

    $this->db->select('date_event');
    $this->db->where('date_event >', $start);
    $this->db->where('date_event <', $end);
    $this->db->where('approved =', 'true');

    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->result();
}
```

xmlhttp.responseText looks like this if I use fore mentioned events to trigger console.log:

[{"date_event":"2015-06-19 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-05 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-03 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-30 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-30 00:00:00"}]

Which is exactly what I want (or is it?). Now I would like get the day (03, 05, 19, 30 in the above example). So I can use them to highlight td elements with corresponding value. And the frontend code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        var xmlhttp;

        function loadXMLDoc(url, cfun) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfun;

            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        //functional code for this feature goes HERE!
        function highlightEvents(date) {
            loadXMLDoc("calendar/events_per_month/" + date, function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {

                    var monthEvents = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    console.log("all posts for this month: " + monthEvents);
                    //var array = $.parseJSON(monthEvents);
                }
            });
        }


        $('.SS_calendar').datepicker()
                .on('changeMonth', function (e) {
                    var date = new Date($('.SS_calendar').datepicker('getMonth'));
                    var currMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth() + 1;
                    var currYear = String(e.date).split(" ")[3];
                    highlightEvents(currMonth + '-' + currYear);
                });
});
```

For those who are willing to help - thank you!

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding your question correctly - is your goal to go from `"[{"date_event":"2015-06-19 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-05 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-03 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-30 00:00:00"},{"date_event":"2015-06-30 00:00:00"}]"` to `[03, 05, 19, 30]`?

Comment: yes it is. [3, 5 ,19 ,30] to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your clarification above, this is the simplest thing I can come up with:

```
var monthsJson = JSON.parse(monthEvents);
var days = [];
monthsJson.forEach(function(dateObj) {
    var date = new Date(dateObj.date_event);
    days.push(date.getDate()); // gets the day of the month
                               // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
});
//days would be an array like [19, 5, 3, 30, 30]
```

You may want to remove duplicates depending on how many you're processing and how you plan to highlight your `td`'s.

Not sure how to address the rest of your question but you've done a lot of work (all of the hard parts, really) already. Take it easy on yourself and others. :)

Comment: Works nicely! And it's a lot more cleaner than what I wrote. Thank you very much!